# Create a Gridview with resizable columns like excel

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, resizable

Please take a look at the screenshot below.
[image]

I am trying to create the page with a gridview. The number of column are so many. There are two issues that I am facing here.

1 ) I am using [Databale js](http://www.datatables.net/) to provide paging, searching and other facilities. As shown in the screenshot due to large number of columns the search box and paging box are not getting applied on proper place.

2 ) If the column is having a large string , Is there any way we can achieve excel like facility. Where default the overflowed text is hidden and when we click on column to re size it can show the whole value. I am using [colresizable](http://quocity.com/colresizable/) plugin for re sizable columns but it is not working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

IdeaSparks ASP.NET CoolControls will work for your problem.

Comment: Where can i find sample implementation of this ?

Comment: [Here](http://shihshu.blogspot.in/2011/09/ideasparks-aspnet-coolcontrols.html).

or [Here](http://johnsobrepena.blogspot.in/2010/01/coolgridview-new-release-resizable.html).

Comment: Is there any possibility http://www.datatables.net/ can work with this control. As this control produces the structure in different way so datatable js is not able wot act upon it.